# Missing name after . operator. bug in Management API script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics-api

I am trying to create a script which will allow me to delete several audiences at once in Google Analytics, but it doesn't work.
Right now I am facing

> Missing name after . operator. (line 9, file "Code").

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Thank you for any help!

Elena

```
function main() {

var settings = {'linkedView':"129244225",
          'linkedAccountId':"1498865",
          'accountId':'11299701',
          'propertyID':'UA-83695085-2'};

 var newAudience = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.delete(
 {
          'accountId':'82272640',
          'propertyID':'UA-83695085-2'
 //    'linkedAdAccounts': [{
 //        'type': 'DBM_LINKS',
 //        'linkedAccountId': settings.linkedAccountId,
 //    'remarketingAudienceId': -2dTA_PARtmitRYvMQhXcQ}
 },


 settings.accountId,
 settings.propertyID);

 Logger.log();

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#how_method_signatures_are_determined),

> Methods named delete in the Google API are named remove in Apps Script, since delete is a reserved word in JavaScript.

Try

```
Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.remove
```

Comment: thank you for your help. It works! But now I am facing another one problem: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 3-4 only (line 9, file "Code"), although I have only 3 parameters: function main() {


 var newAudience = Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.remove(
  {
              'accountId':[settings.accountId],
              'propertyID':[settings.propertyID],
              'remarketingAudienceId': [settings.remarketingAudienceId]
  });

Logger.log();

}

Comment: @Elena Use the auto complete feature in the editor. It'll say the exact syntax to use.

Comment: @Elena The correct syntax is ``Analytics.Management.RemarketingAudience.remove(accountId, webPropertyId, remarketingAudienceId)`` No `{}`

Comment: sorry, one more question. The script worked fine till some point, but now I am facing the error API call to analytics.management.remarketingAudience.delete failed with error: User does not have sufficient permissions for this remarketing audience. (line 16, file "GA Bot Test"). I didn't change anything in the code. Thank you!

Comment: @Elena  Try removing permissions for your app @ https://myaccount.google.com/permissions If that doesn't work, Kindly ask a new question.

Comment: thank you very much! Unfortunately, it didn't work, so I created a new question.